# Android studio error android device monitor

Tags: android

I installed Genymotion plugin on android studio 1.0.1.I want to copy some file to virtual device to test my application.But I get a error 'Failed to create the java virtual machine' when clicking on Android device monitor..How to fix it ?
My studio.exe.vmoptions is:

```
-server
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=250m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio
```

I added:

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
```

I still get error.

Answer (score 0):

I just add:

```
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\javaw.exe
```

It worked for me.